# "Unable to resolve host ""FRMJESPV01":No address associated with hostname"

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, tcp

I try to connect to a remote database Sql Server

Here is my code :

```
try {
            String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            final String connString = "jdbc:sqlserver://FRMJESPV01;DatabaseName=GESFABDO_HISTO;";
            final String username = "sa";
            final String password = "sasql01+";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);


            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
            return conn;
        }
```

But, the following exception is thrown "Unable to resolve host ""FRMJESPV01":No address associated with hostname".

I have already put the android permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml, and I have opened the TCP port 135 on the firewall.

The device is connected to Wi-Fi.

So, how can I solve that problem ?

Comment: Hi Mathieu, do you have the IP of the server, instead of its name ?

Comment: @ChristopheCVB Yes, I have

Comment: Then, replace `FRMJESPV01` by the ip

Comment: @ChristopheCVB I have already tried, it thorows "error : "Socket closed""

Comment: Try also adding IP:Port ?

Comment: @ChristopheCVB same problem

Comment: Can you post the complete error that you have ?

Comment: The error indicates that the hostname `FRMJESPV01` is unknown. Check what the actual DNS name for that host is (maybe it is `FRMJESPV01.local` or something else). Also, you really should **not** connect to a database server directly from an Android application.

Comment: @ChistopheCVB The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel How would you connect indirectly?

Comment: Indirectly via a Back End that provides data through an API

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved the problem, I replaced jdbc by jtds